# How do you keep zoom between pages consistent? via CSS?

Tags: html, css, zooming

I am new to CSS/HTML and couldn't find the answer to this question probably because I'm not using the proper terminology.

I have my separate pages set-up and don't know how to keep the 'user-zoom' consistent among my pages.

For example:

-User is on home.html. User zooms 3 times (control + '+'). Font is much bigger.

-User navigates to about.html. Font and layout is back to the small, default size.

Is there a CSS/HTML/Javascript attribute to keep the pages consistent? Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: For newer HTML coders, it appears that when you run the code on your local machine clicking on a link to another page will "reset" all the zoom [IE and Chrome tested]. However, apparently when you run it from a server the browser will remember the specific zoom and you don't have to worry about it. Hope this helps at least one person!

Comment: I tested on my Chrome and Firefox browser and it keep the same zooming status. The browsers will keep the same status not your CSS ability.

Comment: **EDIT:** Okay I think I'm real dumb. I am currently testing non-live, so are are my browsers opening new html files (resetting the zoom info)? Once I upload it to the server this problem will go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the zoom level is controlled by the browser itself, the way it behaves on a per page basis cannot be adjusted using CSS/HTML/JS.

A workaround would be to create custom zoom buttons with JS and the CSS transform property. You would then want to save the zoom level to a cookie and apply the current saved zoom level to each page the user loads.